# loop over directory and file bash script - awk does not write to file

Tags: bash, awk, find

I would like to traverse through some directories that contain xml files. To each file I would like to apply an awk command and write the output to the file again. The file that is written is empty, though. Why? I use the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash
for f in `find /myDir/ -iname "*.xml"`
do
   awk '/<string name="my\/ attribute" optional="false">/,/<\/string>/ {sub(/<value>(.*)<\/value>/,"<value>none</value>")}1' $f >$f
done
```

Comment: Don't use a `for` loop if your files might contain spaces. Do this: `find ... | while IFS= read -r f; do ...; done`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must use a temporary file:

```
awk ... "$f" > "$f".tmp; mv "$f".tmp "$f"
```

Comment: This works very well. Another problem just hit me. How do I handle filenames that contain spaces? For example "My filename 1.xml".

Comment: @Daniela: new questions should be posted separately. But before you do, please read your shell's manual or search Stack Overflow. There are many, many places where the question of how to handle filenames with spaces is addressed.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not in `awk`, the problem is in the redirection. It is not possible to write to the file you are reading.

Comment: To flesh out the detail, when the shell sees output redirection, it **first** truncates the file to zero-length. **Then** the awk command is executed and operates on an empty file. You do need to write to a temp file. The `-i` option to sed and perl does this behind the scenes.